# How to get the size of a folder using AWK?

Tags: shell, awk

I'm trying to get all the paths and the total size of the folder suing AWK;
my first approach is using this script:

```
BEGIN { OFS=" " }
sub(/^\\/,"/") { path = $0; next }
path == "" { next }
match($0,/^(.*[^ ]) +A +([^ ]+) +(.*)/,a) { print substr(path,2) "\\ " a[2] }
```

But this is giving me the path with size for each file inside the folder, no the total for the folder, so I think it needs to be something using **sum**.

So here is my input:

```
README.txt         A  45  Mon Aug 30 18:50:16 2018        
Test Cases.xlsx         A  1415577  Wed Aug 29 14:00:16 2018
\Qt Database EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0097\Qingl
R0097A+05.00B-00-QingL.JPG          A  6958377  Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
R0097A+05.00B-00-QingLI.JPG         A  2794933  Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
R0097A-00.00B-00-QingLI.JPG         A  2825705  Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
R0097A-00.00B-00-QingLO.JPG         A  1369520  Fri Jun  8 12:53:30 2018
Thumbs.db                           A    20480  13969015Fri Jun  8 13:14:41 2018
\QJ Database EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0098\Qingl
R0098A+05.00B-00-QingL.JPG          A  6958377  Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
R0098A-00.00B-00-QingLO.JPG         A  1369520  Fri Jun  8 12:54:30 2018
Thumbs.db                           A    20480  Fri Jun  8 13:14:41 2018
```

And my output should be something like this:

```
\Qt Database EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0097\Qingl,13969015 
\QJ Database EltraJo\DR0151-populated\DaJa\ASAA Images\k0098\Qingl,8348377
```

Comment: [Parsing `ls` output is problematic](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and doing that for Windows `dir` output applies in spades. You want to use something like `find` or `stat` instead, but they are not entirely portable. Perl would offer a nice solution with a straightforward mapping to the Unix `stat()` system call even for Windows (with the usual caveats).

Comment: If you are on a windows machine, you might be interested in the [sysinternals `du`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896651) command. This should give you the output you are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a refactoring which appears to do what you want.

```
BEGIN { OFS="," }
/^\\/ { if(path) print path, sum; path = $0; sum = 0; next }
path == "" { next }
match($0,/^(.*[^ ]) +A +([^ ]+) +(.*)/,a) { sum+= a[2] }
END { if(path) print path, sum }'
```

The trick is collecting things and printing the result from that when a collection is done. (A common beginner bug is forgetting to print the last collection. Having the same code a second time in `END` is a bit of a wart -- if it were any more complex I'd put that in a function.)

You seem to want comma-separated output, so we set `OFS` to that.

The three-argument `match()` requires GNU Awk.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you say, now, in this solution you could add the files that are directly in the root? for example add another line taking only the root files and print it later? Something like `if($2 ~ /A/ ) print $1`

Comment: I'm sure it can be done. Give it a shot; if you get stuck, post a new question with relevant sample data. (Hint: take out the `path == ""` and instead check if `sum` is larger than zero.) In the meantime, please accept one of the answers here, or post one of your own and accept that.

Answer (score 0):

Why struggling with "awk" for this when you can simply use "du" ?

```
du -sh <dir_name>
```